# Ajax call returning "0000000154" as 108

Tags: javascript, ajax, return-value, jquery-callback

In my web application I am generating a serial number using ajax. Serial Number is always 10 digit long. So, if its less than 10 digit "0"'s are appended at the begining.

I am doing an ajax call and the method is returning the serial number as 108 instead of "0000000154".

I could get "0000000154" as String in my java function but when I get this value in javascript it shows 108.

Why this is happening?

Below is my java code at backend

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/genNextSerialNumber", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String genNextSerialNumber() {
    log.info("generating serial number");
    String serialNumber= employeeService.genNextSerialNumber();
    return serialNumber;
}
```

Below is my front end code.

```
$.getJSON(url +"?t="+getTimestamp(), function(nextSerialNumber) {
    var nextSerialNumberObj = document.getElementById("nextSerialNumber");
    alert(nextSerialNumber);
    nextSerialNumberObj .value = nextSerialNumber;
});
```

Comment: Yes, your best bet will be to retrieve it as string.

Comment: does your json response return '0000000012' or 0000000012 ?

Comment: @xFortyFourx. I am returning it as String only. See I have updated my question.

Comment: can we see the response text?

Comment: It's almost often preferable to use console.log instead of alert. For example you see if it's a string or a number.

Comment: @dystroy. Using console.log  gives me error saying that console is undefines.

Comment: The important part of the javascript code seems to be missing. Hard to see what happens.

Comment: @Joseph. How do I see the response text?

Comment: @ashish : consider debugging on chrome if you don't know how to see messages and objects easily in your current browser.

Comment: `console.log(nextSerialNumber)` instead of alert and watch the console (if any). If you can't use a browser with a debugger, then install DebugBar for IE

Comment: @dystroy. I am not allowed to use anything other than IE 7. Company policies :(

Comment: @Ashish I'll suggest you a very easy and not so "ethical" solution, and here it goes, nextSerialNumberObj .value = "" + nextSerialNumber; Since I'm adding a "" BEFORE the variable, the whole thing will be considered as string and will not automatically treat as number.

Comment: You need to debug it properly with proper tools. Install debugbar. If that's also denied in company policy, your company will suffer in future

Comment: @xFortyFourx. I tried adding "" before but its not working. I think may be Spring MVC is converting  it to number while returning from the java. So this way I will always get it as the number in javascript.

Comment: @Ashish, you said you already converted it to string before sending right ? Please make sure that you are sending it as string and not number, make sure it's not rounded off to 12 before sending it to your html page.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything with it unless the data sent to you is in `String` form. integers with leading zeroes [are in octal form](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp6TJ/).

something like this

```
{
    "foo":0000000012 //gives me a "10". octal
}
```

is different from:

```
{
    "foo":"0000000012" //gives "0000000012"
}
```

Comment: First one is octal number, not binary

Comment: @Joseph. I think this is what is happening. 0000000154 is getting alerted as 108. So, its treating 0000000154 as octal and then converting to decimal 108. How do I fix this now?

Comment: @Ashish put the request url into the address bar and see the result. let's just make sure we know where that "conversion" occurs.

Comment: @Joseph. Strange . When i put the request url into the address bar and try to see the result, it returns blank gif. ?????

Comment: @Joseph. Well... This is not how I wanted to do it but I added that String in list and then returned that list from java instead of returning the String and it works. :-)